# Index & Match to return text value

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula

Having error in my formula.

How do i get it to display matched text output in column referencing on a column?

F11 to display A1 looking up output produce by formulas in rows above it that is not special character "-".

G11 to display B1 looking up output produce by formulas in rows above it that is not special character "-".

H11 to display B6 looking up output produce by formulas in rows above it that is not special character "-".

As shown in the picture below, formula below is my current input to reference column which produces error.

```
 =INDEX(F5:F10,MATCH(A5:A10,A5:A10,0))
```

[image]

Comment: are those hyphens or zeroes formatted to show hyphens?

Comment: Is actual hyphen. Which is used in current IF formula to display false value if it doesn't matches

Comment: You can't pass range as first argument of `MATCH`, it should be value or single cell reference. Can you include expected results?

Comment: Expected Values as in A1,A2,B1,B6,A6 & A7? Then it would have to include   another 7 expected values which is not shown above.

Comment: H11 to show B6 or B1? I am confused. Anyway INDEX/MATCH may become involved with Array Entry. I would try to use a formula like `=LOOKUP(2,1/(F5:F10=$A$5:$A$10),F5:F10)` in cell F11 and copy across.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij
Corrected it. Should be B6. Your formula works. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Edit, you could use a formula like

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(F5:F10=$A$5:$A$10),F5:F10)`

Copy it across!

If there's going to only one entry and others as dash (-) then following can also be used.

`=SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10),"-","")`

**Explanation for LOOKUP:**

We simply compare values in formula column (F in this case) with values in Column A by using 
`(F5:F10=$A$5:$A$10)` which produces results like `TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE`

when these results are used to divide 1 then they're coerced to numbers (TRUE=1, FALSE=0) so the resultant array looks like `1,#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!`.

We are looking in TRUE result which will be always equal to 1. So we are using a number larger than 1 i.e. 2 as LOOKUP uses binary search. Any large number can be used.

And then outer LOOKUP simply returns the matched item from passed array.

You can precisely see this by using Formula Evaluate option in the ribbon `Formulas >> Formula Auditing >> Evaulate Formula`.

Comment: What does 2,1 does in the loopup?
Mind explaining?